# Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up For documentation on this error

Tags: selenium, xpath

I can't find this element; it is showing an error like:

> Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it
>   was looked up For documentation on this error

```
WebElement w4= d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='businessPartner' 
               and @oninput='isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()']"));
   expcitlyWait(w4);
   w4.sendKeys("DURIAN INDUSTRIES LTD");
   w4.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
   w4.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

Example Input which should be found:

```
<input id="isc_T3" 
 name="businessPartner"
 oninput="isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()"
 class="OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired" 
 type="TEXT" tabindex="2239" 
 style="WIDTH:233px;HEIGHT:19px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" 
 autocomplete="OFF" 
 spellcheck="true" 
 $187="$188" 
 $186="isc_OBSelectorItem_1" 
 handlenativeevents="false" 
/>
```

Comment: look at your page, is there an input with this @oninput function ? 
Are you using selenium with php ? the $303 part looks wrong to me

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes oninput function is there and i am using selenium with java.  <input id="isc_UQ" class="OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired" type="TEXT" tabindex="2239" style="WIDTH:233px;HEIGHT:19px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" autocomplete="OFF" oninput="isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()" spellcheck="true"

Comment: but in this example the name is not there. Can you post the html of  the whole object you try to grab, (one object should be enough)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo ble id="isc_T6" class="OBFormFieldSelectControl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="cursor:default;WIDTH:258px;" $187="$19c" $186="isc_OBSelectorItem_1" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input id="isc_T3" class="OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired" type="TEXT" tabindex="2239" style="WIDTH:233px;HEIGHT:19px;-moz-user-focus:normal;" autocomplete="OFF" oninput="isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()" spellcheck="true" $187="$188" $186="isc_OBSelectorItem_1" handlenativeevents="false" name="businessPartner"/>

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem seems to be, that the element you are referencing as "w4" does not exist anymore, or not on the same place. 
This error happens, if something on the page has changed, between your xpath call and the call for w4

Try to use the absolute Xpath. (To find w4, and to find the input on d).
So your code should look somehting like that:

```
expcitlyWait(d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='businessPartner' 
           and @oninput='isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()']")));
d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='businessPartner' 
           and @oninput='isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()']"))
           .sendKeys("DURIAN INDUSTRIES LTD");
d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='businessPartner' 
           and @oninput='isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()']"))
           .sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='businessPartner' 
           and @oninput='isc_OBSelectorItem_1.$303()']"))
           .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: i tried with absolute x path but getting same issue ,-//table[@id='isc_T6']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input

Comment: i tried with your code but still getting same issue -Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
For documentation on this error,

Comment: I tried a lot for this element and i got frustrated, any other solution for this type of error

Comment: @Avnish Rathore
First you should improve your question, add full code, full markup, and the most important thing, always tell us in what line the code fails with what exception.